# Binding a DataGrid when already having a DataContext declared in a Window----WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am running into an issue that I haven't been able to resolve and although I've looked at a few similar posts, I haven't found anything that explains my situation.

Basically I have a WPF Window:

```
<Window x:Class="NewGame">
    <DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
```

In the class I implement INotifyPropertyChanged to utilize bindings for some properties I have set up to update dynamically using XAML.  For instance, I have a DB that has Primary, Secondary and Trim Colors(Hex codes) listed for teams, and the properties automatically will update based on changing the team.  So I have the BorderBrush, Foreground and Backgrounds on various things auto-updating in XAML using:

```
<Foreground="{Binding Path=MyPrimColor}">
<Background={Binding Path=MySecColor}">
<BorderBrush={Binding Path=MyTrimColor}">
```

, etc...each could be any of the properties, it doesn't matter, those are all working fine.

Now, I have a DataGrid which I need to bind to a DataTable to display the players on the team, and that is where I have run into the issue.  It tells me the "Items Collection must be empty before using Itemsource" and throws an exception.  This was never an issue until I started using the databindings in XAML, when I had things set in code behind, everything worked fine, but I also know this isn't the way things are supposed to be done, which is why I want to have it working with the XAML data-bindings.

I created MyDT a property as DataTable, and when I try to bind 
`<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDT}">`, it causes the Foreground and Background binding paths to try to bind to the Data.DataTable object as well which obviously throws an error.

I have seen some say I need to use `<DataGrid.DataContext>` inside the `<datagrid>` but I haven't gotten that to work either. I understand where the problem is coming from---I already have the bindings set at a higher level, but I just don't know how to fix it in XAML by only binding the DataGrid to the DT property while leaving the others to bind to the class level.

Here is the full code section in XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="TeamRosterDT"
 Height="400"
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
 Foreground="{Binding Path=MyTrimColor}"
 RowBackground="{Binding Path=MySecColor}"
 AlternatingRowBackground="{Binding Path=MyPrimColor}"
 CanUserAddRows="False"
 CanUserDeleteRows="False"
 CanUserResizeColumns="False"
 ColumnWidth="Auto"     
 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
 ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 Opacity="0.8"     
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
 Visibility="Hidden"
 DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDT}">
    <DataGridColumnHeader Style="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}" />
    <DataGridCell HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />

</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no need to change DataContext (`DataContext="{Binding Path=MyDT}"`), only bind ItemsSource (`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDT}">` or `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyDT.DefaultView}">`)

Exception is thrown because of incorrect items declaration (lines with DataGridColumnHeader, DataGridCell). They are added to Items list which is not supported when ItemsSource is set

Answer (score 0):

I got the Exceptions resolved(I believe) by using:

```
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=MyPrimColor}" />
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=MyTrimColor}" />
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
<DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

However, the DataTable does not update properly---when the XAML is initialized its an empty DB, which is then filled and filtered according to what team is selected. When a new team is selected, the DT is simply filtered, not refilled. However, since I suppose this technically isn't a "change" to the DT itself, it doesn't fire the OnPropertyChanged event.  How can I get it to update properly using XAML triggers, or is than an event I can utilize when the DB refilters?

Is where I would use an ObservableCollection?